# Bonjour defeating wireless isolation?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, macbook, vlan, bonjour

I have two MacBook Pros and a Cisco RV110W wireless router.

I have created a VLAN with all ports untagged and I linked this VLAN to a Wi-Fi with the option "Wireless Isolation with SSID" on.

From both MacBooks I can successfully connect to the Wi-Fi (previously created) and if I try to ping between them, they can't see each other, which is something I'm happy with.

The problem occurred when I saw in Finder the name of the other MacBook Pro (this has screen sharing (VNC) enabled), so I clicked on it and then provided the credentials, and I was able to connect to the other MacBook Pro, which I thought was not possible due to the Isolation option I enabled in the router.

**First Question:** How is it possible they can see each other, if pinging between them showed me that they can't communicate with one another, and the Wi-Fi VLAN has isolation enabled?

**Second Question:** Is Bonjour enabling the communication between them?

**Third Question:** How can I truly isolate both MacBooks using this router?

Comment: Turn File Sharing off. And see if it works but also check out [This Article](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NetServices/Articles/faq.html) may help out a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check in `System Preferences > iCloud` to see if they're both signed into the same iCloud account and both have Back to My Mac enabled. If you do, then you could have been connecting that way, rather than a direct LAN connection.

Note that if you have more than one user account on either Mac, you'll have to log into each user account to check this, as different users can be logged into different iCloud accounts.

Comment: Hi Spiff, thank you for your response. In one Mac (the one with the VNC enabled) I'm logged in with iCloud but the option Back to My Mac is disabled. The second Mac, I have not logged in with iCloud. Any other ideas?